# How to memorize a macro argument in m4?

Tags: macros, m4

I want to memorize the argument of an `m4` macro call for further usage, i.e. use another macro symbol as a kind of variable with which I can recall that argument later.

My `m4` session, however, doesn't work out as expected:

```
define(`A',define(`B',$1))
⇒ 
A(17)
⇒ 
B
⇒ 
defn(`B')
⇒$1
```

I simply want the value of `B` to be resolved to 17 if the last call of `A` was `A(17)`. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Just found it:

```
define(`A',`define(B,$1)')
```

will do the trick. By quoting, the resolution of define is postponed to the actual call of `A'.